# Determine if app has been closed without using OnStop()

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

What I want to do is send a logout request to my backend server when the user quits my app (can happen during any Activity, there are many).

It seems like I cannot use `OnStop()` as I have a gallery chooser and camera Intent and when these are started, `OnPause` and `OnStop` are called. I need a way to definitively know that the app has closed.

I've read up about using a `Service`/`BroadcastReceiver` or even a `LocalBroadcastManager`, or possibly tying the request to when the home button has been clicked.

I can't check if the application has been sent to background as this would be true for a camera/gallery Intent starting as well as the app being sent to background. I've also tried checking the package name of the activity being started but this may be variable on other devices (e.g. gallery might have a different package name).

Any advice/direction is much appreciated.

Edit: I've discovered there isn't really a way to intercept a home button press. Still looking for a solution!

Comment: OnStop() or OnDestroy() ?.When does this case occur ,remove from recent apps?

Comment: @sunilsunny I cannot use `OnDestroy()` as this is not guaranteed to be called, and `OnStop` can be called in multiple scenarios. The user will likely kill the app from recent apps, yes.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia nope!

Comment: @LKB  so what did you do? Sorry about caps lock in the last comment

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem like this,I used a Service to solve my problem.This is what I have done

In main activity

```
 ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
 public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder binder) {
            ((KillingNotificationBar.KillBinder) binder).service.startService(new Intent(
                    Main.this, KillingNotificationBar.class));
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }

    };
 bindService(new Intent(Main.this,
                    KillingNotificationBar.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

KillingNotificationBar  class

```
public class KillingNotificationBar extends Service {
private final IBinder mBinder = new KillBinder(this);
public class KillBinder extends Binder {
    public final Service service;
    public KillBinder(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    you will know if the activity is destroyed
}
}
```

add this in your manifest

```
 <service android:name=".services.KillingNotificationBar"/>
```

**Note**
It will take 1-5 seconds to get executed.